# HTML Input type "image" if above a few pixels. Trouble aligning

Tags: html, css, sass

I hate doing this. Don't think it's to much code tho... I'm just dumb found right now. Don't know why my magnifying glass image is not aligning correctly with my input text.

Any suggestions anybody need some help

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div id="pagetop">
        <ul id="title">
          <li id="logo"><img src="images/creativebug.png" alt=""></li>
          <li>Classes</li>
          <li>Inspiration</li>
          <li>Instructor</li>
          <li>Calander</li>
          <li>Free</li>
          <li><span id="CBTV">CBTV</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id='buttons'>
          <li><button id="trial">Start Free Trial</button></li>
          <li><button id="login">Log in</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="search-area">
        <select>
          <option>CLASSES</option>
        </select
        ><input id="textsearch" type="text" placeholder="Search"
        ><input id="mag" type="image" src="images/mag.png">
      </div>

    </div>
    <hr id="line">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS - (USING SASS - think its cleaner...)

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald)

// Font Variables
$Oswald: Oswald, serif

// Styles
body
    font-family: $Oswald
    font-size: 40px
    margin: 0px

.header
    margin: 0 150px

.content
    height: 1000px
    padding-top: 200px

#pagetop
    top: 0px
    width: 100%
    background: white
    color: #000
    font-size: 18px
    padding-top: 0px
    overflow: hidden

#pagetop
    ul
        li
            list-style: none
            text-transform: uppercase
            float: left

#pagetop
    #title
        li
            margin-right: 22px
            margin-top: 6px

#pagetop
    #title
        #logo
            margin-top: 0px

#pagetop
    li
        #CBTV
            color: #FF4B55


//search area

.header
    .search-area
        select
            height: 32px
            border: 1px solid #eee
            outline: none
            background-color: #B9B9B9
            border-radius: 0px
            appearance: none
            padding-left: 10px
            padding-right: 10px
            border-top-left-radius: 5px
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px
            border-right: none
            display: inline-block

.header
    .search-area
        #mag
            border-top-right-radius: 5px
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px

.header
    .search-area
        #textsearch
            border-right: none
            width: 360px
            padding-left: 8px

.header
    .search-area
        input
            height: 30px
            padding: 0px
            border: 1px solid #eee
            outline: none
            display: inline-block

.header
    .search-area
        text-align: center


hr
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee

// right side buttons
#pagetop
    #buttons
        float: right
        padding: 0px
        margin: 0 0
        margin-right: 40px
        margin-top: 4px

#pagetop
    #buttons
        li
            margin-right: 4px

#trial
  color: #fff
  padding: 8px 16px
  text-align: center
  text-decoration: none
  display: inline-block
  border: none
  border-radius: 7px
  text-transform: uppercase
  background-color: #FF4B55

#login
  color: #fff
  padding: 8px 16px
  text-align: center
  text-decoration: none
  display: inline-block
  border: none
  border-radius: 7px
  text-transform: uppercase
  background-color: #666666
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adjust the top-margin of the class #mag this may be your solution. Shoot a link and I would be happy to assist further.